# Is there any way to configure Jenkins without using GUI?

Tags: jenkins

I want to setup master and slave relationship in Jenkins without opening the jenkins link.
Is it possible to change the config.xml and form this setup?
The value of slave node will be  passed as parameter and will be put in the config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can try this following solution. Actually my current Test framework is working as [CI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) configured just like you want. What you need to do is:

- find suitable [Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins) that you can use and support
- set your Jenkins jobs to get configurations form your *Code project*  e.g. from [VCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Code_Control_System)
  (goto Job Config > Source Code Management > Check-out Strategy must be set to 'as much as possible')

This can be done in following steps:

- install Powershell/Batch plugin for Jenkins
- prepare **update** script and put it in your code project
- every time you need to configure your Jenkins job, just set properties in your script
- update/commit your code project into the VCS
- run your Jenkins job

As example you can use this sample batch code as configurable *pre-steps*:

```
@echo off
call %WORKSPACE%/jenkins-scripts/set-properties.bat "myRootFolder=/user/project" "rootRefDataFolder=12345" "standartVersion=1.2.3" "alwaysReload=false"
call %WORKSPACE%/jenkins-scripts/do-something-else.bat
```

And this one as *set-properties.bat*:

```
@echo off
echo ----------------------------------------------------------
SET PROP_NAME=base.Project.properties
echo Task: [Update %PROP_NAME%] started
echo Workspace: %WORKSPACE%
SET PROJECT_PATH=projectPath=%WORKSPACE:\=/%
SET RESULT_FOLDER=testResultFolder=report
SET PROP_PATH=%WORKSPACE%\test\resources

DEL "%PROP_PATH%\%PROP_NAME%"
echo %PROJECT_PATH%>> "%PROP_PATH%\%PROP_NAME%"
echo %RESULT_FOLDER%>> "%PROP_PATH%\%PROP_NAME%"
for %%x in (%*) do echo %%~x>> "%PROP_PATH%\%PROP_NAME%"

echo Current properties:
echo __________________________________________________________
type "%PROP_PATH%\%PROP_NAME%"
echo __________________________________________________________
echo Task: [Update %PROP_NAME%] finished
echo ----------------------------------------------------------
```

Just be sure to *set your own paths and variables*.